# JQuery Mobile - assign event handlers to dynamically created buttons

Tags: jquery, mobile, button, jquery-mobile, event-handling

I get a json array back from the server and then I loop through it and add buttons (data-role="button") to a page.  I call $("a[data-role='button']").button() in each iteration.

My problem is that each button needs to call the same event handler but with a different id.
If I were doing this in Java/GWT, I'd pass the id to the constructor of my custom implementation of the event handler for each button.

How would I achieve the same in JQuery Mobile?

The code below creates the two buttons, but nothing happens when I click on them.

Here's my code:

```
success: function(data) {
                $('#personPage div[data-role="content"]').empty();
                for (var i = 0;i < data.length;i++){
                    $('#personPage div[data-role="content"]').append('<a href="#" id="person_' + data[i].id + '" data-role="button"  data-id="person_' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].name + '</a>');
                    $("a[data-role='button']").button();
                    $("#person_" + data[i].id).bind('click', function(event) {
                          alert('It WOrks');
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
```

Comment: I know this is an old question, but your code works for me http://jsfiddle.net/ZngWR/

Answer (score 1):

When you add buttons(build the html to be appended), also add a data-id attribute with the value as the id from the JSON Array. So the html tag would finally look like this:

```
<a data-role="button" data-id="1234">1234 Button</a>
```

And in the onclick event handler get the id like this:

```
var id = $(this).data('id');
```

That's it.

Refer http://api.jquery.com/data/ to read more on data attributes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  But how do I specify the click handler itself?  I've tried many different ways and its not capturing click event.  I've added my code to the question.

Comment: $(document).delegate('a','click',function(event){
var id = $(this).data('id');
});

Comment: @AkashBudhia You just saved me form so much frustration. Thank you so much.